# ¿Por qué el resultado de una operación aritmetica con DateTime es de tipo TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde el usuario debe introducir dos fechas y he necesitado de realizar calculos con dichas fechas:

```
DateTime Desde, Hasta, Resultado; // Las variables DateTime que utilizo
```

Y dentro del codigo que maneja los calculos necesito hacer una resta entre las variables `Desde` y `Hasta`:

```
// ...
Resultado = Desde - Hasta;
// ...
```

Mi problema *(tal vez por temas de rendimiento)* es que necesito realizar la serie de operaciones y almacenar los resultados en una variable de tipo `DateTime`.

Al intentar realizar el cast obtengo el error:

```
No se puede convertir 'TimeSpan' a 'DateTime'
```

Y si intento asignar directamente el valor en la variable:

```
No se puede convertir implicitamente 'TimeSpan' a 'DateTime'
```

La pregunta es, ¿Por qué el resultado de esta operación con `DateTime` es de tipo `TimeSpan`?

Comment: necesitas saber como convertir `TimeSpan`  a `Datetime` o solo el porqué?

Comment: En este caso solo el por qué.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La operacion de dos fechas da un intervalo de tiempo en horas, minutos y segundos, eso es lo que representa un TimeSpan.

Si restas el dia hoy con el de ayer tienes 24hs de diferencia, eso es lo que contendra el TimeSpan.

Convertir de forma directa no puedes, pero si podrias añadir a un DateTime el valor que tenga el TimeSpan

Algo como ser

```
TimeSpan Resultado = Desde - Hasta;

DateTime hoy = DateTime.Today;
DateTime fechaFinal = hoy.Add(Resultado);
```

En este caso tendras la fecha actual + la diferencia en horas, munitos y segundos que dio como resultado la resta.

**>>pero por qué no se puede castear a DateTime un valor de tipo TimeSpan?**

A nivel conceptual el dato representa cosas distintas, el DateTime es una fecha y hora en un momento determinado del tiempo, en cambio el TimeSpan es un intervalo de tiempo.

El TimeSpan dice por ejemplo 2hs 30min, NO representa las 2:30AM o las 2:30PM de un dia determinado sino que son dos horas y media es un intervalo de tiempo, es por eso que al ser conceptos de tiempo distintos no se pueden mapear directo.

Si puedes a una fecha y hora concreta (DateTime) sumar un intervalo de tiempo (TimeSpan)

Comment: La solución funciona perfectamente, pero por qué no se puede castear a `DateTime` un valor de tipo `TimeSpan`?, pues al efectuar una operación entre `DateTime` se obtiene una fecha tecnicamente "imaginaria" que contiene el intervalo de tiempo entre ambos valores.

Comment: es que a nivel conceptual el dato representa cosas distintas, el DateTime es una fecha y hora en un momento determinado del tiempo, en cambio el TimeSpan es un intervalo de tiempo. El TimeSpan dice por ejemplo 2hs 30min, NO representa las 2:30AM o las 2:30PM de un dia determinado sino que son dos horas y media es un intervalo de tiempo, es por eso que al ser conceptos de timepo distintos no se pueden mapear directo. Puede a una fecha y hora concreta (DateTime) sumar un intervalo de tiempo (TimeSpan)

Comment: Oh, ya entiendo la razón!

Comment: El contenido del comentario es la verdadera respuesta y debería ir en el cuerpo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza bueno consejo, copie el comentario como parte de la respuesta